# Using grid-span w/ a grid initialized with the compound grid function

Tags: singularitygs

After you utilize the `compound` function after importing `singularitygs/extras`, how to use `grid-span` to then alternate between the two (or more) grids we instantiated with that function--the third parameter of the `grid-span` mixin, `$grid`, or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with [compound grids](https://github.com/snugug/north#compound-grids), say a compound 3/4 column grid, you aren't using either a 3 column grid or a 4 column grid, you are creating a new asymmetric grid based on the properties of the grids you are compounding. Take a look at the following image:

[image: Compound 3-4 grid]

The top section shows the final compound grid, with the middle section showing the grid split into thirds and bottom section showing the grid split into quarters. You span the final compound grid as normal, just keeping in mind how you want to span each compound.